# Is there any way to UVW unwrap a mesh without applying its modifiers first?

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers, uv, texture-baking

Imagine I have a plane with a solidify modifier and a bevel. I now wish to UVW unwrap the model so that I can bake its materials. When I go into the UV editor, only the geometry of the original plane is available. Is there any way of unwrapping the modified model (with the solidify and bevel) without destructively applying the modifiers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

TL;DNR: It depends on the modifier:

If the modifier creates geometry that you need to unwrap, then yes, otherwise no.  You can't unwrap the geometry from your solidify modifier without applying it for example, but you might be able to put seams in the right place on a model you've used a subdivision surface modifier on.

But some modifiers come with the ability to avoid needing to unwrap.  The solidify modifier allows you to add materials to the generated geometry, and sometimes that serves well enough; for example.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, I missed the alert. Thanks so much for your answer. I thought this might be the case. It is unfortunate since it invalidates many of the benefits of non-destructive editing. I wish there was a UV modifer that takes a snapshot of the mesh...